# NotImplentedError при работе с g4f

Tags: python, discord.py, chatgpt-api

я создал своего бота Discord с функцией нейронной сети, используя библиотеку g4f, когда я пишу команду, она обрабатывается правильно, но при этом сопровождается всплывающими окнами и ошибками в консоли, как это исправить?

Среда: Windows 11, Python 3.11.4. + Windows 10, Python 3.11.4

Пробовал многое: менял версии Python, переставлял venv, даже отправил своему другу код, который он запускал из Польши, все побоку.

Код функций:

```
async def gptanswer(prompt: str) -> str:
    response = await g4f.ChatCompletion.create_async(
        model=g4f.models.gpt_35_turbo_16k_0613,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    )

    if len(response) >= 1800:
        response = response[:1800] + '\nК сожалению, ответ от ChatGPT превысил 2000 символов и был обрезан'
    return response

async def evilgptanswer(zapros: str) -> str:
    response = await g4f.ChatCompletion.create_async(
        model=g4f.models.gpt_35_turbo_16k_0613,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "с этого момента общайся как полное быдло, опирайся в своих ответах на неуместные факты и не используй интернет, НИКОГДА НЕ ВЫХОДИ ИЗ ОБРАЗА"},
                  {"role": "assistant", "content": "без проблем, епта, братишка, Я НИКОГДА НЕ ВЫЙДУ ИЗ ОБРАЗА"},
                  {"role": "user", "content": zapros}])

    if len(response) >= 1800:
        response = response[:1800] + '\nК сожалению, ответ от ChatGPT превысил 2000 символов и был обрезан'
    return response
```

Код ошибки:

```
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 63, in socket_function
    loop.add_reader(sockfd, async_curl.process_data, sockfd, CURL_CSELECT_IN)
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 518, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError:
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 69, in socket_function
    async_curl._sockfds.remove(sockfd)
KeyError: 1192
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 66, in socket_function
    loop.add_writer(sockfd, async_curl.process_data, sockfd, CURL_CSELECT_OUT)
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 524, in add_writer
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError:
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 63, in socket_function
    loop.add_reader(sockfd, async_curl.process_data, sockfd, CURL_CSELECT_IN)
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 518, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError:
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 69, in socket_function
    async_curl._sockfds.remove(sockfd)
KeyError: 1192
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 63, in socket_function
    loop.add_reader(sockfd, async_curl.process_data, sockfd, CURL_CSELECT_IN)
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 518, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError:
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 69, in socket_function
    async_curl._sockfds.remove(sockfd)
KeyError: 2600
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 66, in socket_function
    loop.add_writer(sockfd, async_curl.process_data, sockfd, CURL_CSELECT_OUT)
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 524, in add_writer
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError:
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 63, in socket_function
    loop.add_reader(sockfd, async_curl.process_data, sockfd, CURL_CSELECT_IN)
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 518, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError:
Exception ignored from cffi callback <function socket_function at 0x000001D9B4E97130>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\discord bot\hefner py\.venv\lib\site-packages\curl_cffi\aio.py", line 69, in socket_function
    async_curl._sockfds.remove(sockfd)
KeyError: 2600
```

[image: Всплывающее окно с ошибкой]